# What should be inside "Parameters" and what in "Resoures" in AWS Cloudformation json template?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I started to change/add more things, in big cloudformation json template of big project. When file was uploaded, I get error:

> Error Template validation error: Invalid template parameter property
>   'Properties'

I didn't liked AWS documentation. And looking for simple explanation what should be in "Parameters" and what in "Resoures" in AWS Cloudformation json template?
Or what exactly I can understand from that error output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Parameters section contains information that you want to provide to your stack when it is configured. For example, you may want to create some services that all share a common S3 bucket that already exists. In that case, one of the Parameters would be the name of that S3 bucket.

The Resources section describes the things you want your stack to create: EC2 instances, SQS queues, SNS topics, and so on.

Comment: So what exactly this error trying to say me? One of the parameters in "properties" of "Resoures" used not properly? Because I have in Resourses 78 properties :)

Comment: I'd need more details. The parameters being discussed in that error message are not from the Parameters section, they are simply values you are filling in for properties. And one of them seems to be wrong. For example, you might have specified an invalid instance-type for an EC2 instance. There are so many kinds of resources with so many different properties that I can't guess what the problem would be without lots more information.